# Use authorization code from js client to fetch data with php from user (offline access)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-api

i try to fetch data via php backend using google API js library.

At the first step, user will authorize app through OAuth in the frontend

```
const scopes = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit',
]

gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
        this.gaAuth = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: '965399848242-skdqgktduruufpqtcuhvm9oqlpk21qq4.apps.googleusercontent.com',

            scope: scopes.join(' ')
        }).grantOfflineAccess().then(
            success => {

                // send and save authorization code to server/database

            },
            error => {
            });
    });
```

Now i want to fetch analytics data via php using authorization code, which will received from frontend (see code below)

```
  $googleClient = new Google_Client();
  $googleClient->setAuthConfig(storage_path('google/client_secret.json'));
  $googleClient->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authorizationCodeFromFrontend);

  $googleClient->setScopes([
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics'
   ]);

  $analyticsClient = new Google_Service_Analytics($googleClient); 

  return response()->json($analyticsClient
            ->management_accounts
            ->listManagementAccounts()
            ->getItems());
```

But i get this following error:

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"required","message":"Login Required","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Login Required"}}
```

Edit:
After some debugging i saw i get an error from **fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode** method:

```
 'error' => 'invalid_grant',
 'error_description' => 'Bad Request',
```

Comment: It sounds like you haven't yet understood OAuth. Make sure you know the roles of Authorization Code, Access Token and Refresh Token before writing any more code.

Comment: Google provides a one-time-code flow. the code can be stored in the backend to access data offline or i'm wrong? I can challenge the client-auth flow and can access the code. On same origin like example.com the code above works fine for me. But the backend services exists on different one like api.example.com

Comment: Like I said, make sure you understand the roles of the AC, RT, and AT before you start to code.